# How can I get wavs to play in the browser?

Tags: firefox

I'm trying to share my music on my website, but I can't seem to get wavs to play in the browser. They're correctly served with `audio/x-wav` and I thought that was enough to get it to work. I tried disabling CSP and nosniff to no avail. This is what the response headers look like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000;
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self'; frame-ancestors *:*; base-uri 'none'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; form-action 'none'
X-Frame-Options: ALLOWALL
X-XSS-Protection: 0
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Type: audio/x-wav
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "1262751047"
Last-Modified: Sat, 07 Sep 2019 23:56:44 GMT
Content-Length: 2953260
Date: Sun, 08 Sep 2019 12:53:24 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.45
```

I don't know if firefox just doesn't support wavs as it says it does. But I can't figure out how to fix this.

How do I tell firefox to allow in-browser playback?

Comment: Does it play in other browsers? What is the HTML you served it with?

Comment: Why not convert it to a supported format? At the very least, it'd save a lot of bandwidth - `.wav` is uncompressed, leaving even a short clip typically multi-megabytes in size.

Comment: @MichaelHampton no HTML. didn't try other browsers but I think they also tell the user to download.

Comment: @ceejayoz I can't find a list of supported formats for in-browser playback anywhere. if you have such a list, I'd like to know.

Comment: @SoniEx2 MP3 is supported basically everywhere. https://caniuse.com/#feat=mp3

Comment: @ceejayoz that says nothing about hotlinked audio files.

Comment: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox Oh, and you still need to try it in another browser.

Comment: Supported audio formats by browser. WAV should be supported by Firefox. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @SoniEx2 Why are you hotlinking? Use the `<audio>` tag if you want to play in-browser.